# where the setting is stored in FSE, not theme.json

Tags: full-site-editing, theme.json

I added a custom font to the TT4 theme via theme.json. I'm not able to see the font name when I go to Editor>Styles in Typography I cannot see the font. But once I go to my host and rename a folder name of my Theme, I can see the font name in Styles!!!

Note: I want to add a custom Arabic font to my whole website, but can't.